# Azure Data Factory: Upload filesystem binary files (jpg or png) to varbinary column in on-premises SQL Database using self-hosted Integration Runtime

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I am trying to upload a folder (about 7300 items) of picture files (jpg or png) from the filesystem to an on-premises SQL database table called DocumentBinary:

[DocumentBinary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruDWF.png)

I want to use a Data Factory pipeline for this.
I am using a self-hosted Integration Runtime to connect to the SQL Server database.

I have searched all over but cannot find an example of how to do this.

I have tried using a 'Copy Data' activity with a binary source dataset for the files in the filesystem (pointing at the file folder), and a SQL Server sink dataset for the database table, but Data Factory shows the following error message:

> Sink must be binary when source is binary dataset.

(both source and sink need to be binary).

I have tried using a DelimitedText dataset with no delimiters, as the source, but I get the following error:

> Row/Column delimiter cannot be empty string ... when dataset is referenced in Copy Data Activity Name.

Comment: FWIW, it's anti-patternish to store files in the database themselves. Best practice is to store them on disk somewhere and store the file location in the database instead.

Comment: @J.D. Thanks for the quick reply. That's an alternative that we will have to consider.

Comment: No problem. Sorry I'm not versed in Azure Data Factory otherwise I'd offer up an answer. But some of the reasons it's bad practice for storing files in the database is because it's error-prone and bloated. Presumably (hopefully) you're taking backups of your database system, and those backups will contain redundant copies of those files as well. File systems were designed for files, database systems for data.

Comment: I'm afraid we are using NOP, and that uses a PictureBinary table that stores the pictures in a varbinary column. So, we would prefer to go with the binary upload to database, using Data Factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sink must be binary when source is binary dataset.

Cause of error is **In Azure Data Factory If you are trying to copy Binary file then your Source and Sink both should be binary dataset**

As per your requirement I want to suggest you a Workaround or alternative to overcome this issue.

- First, I took `Get Metadata activity` and set Field list as `Childitems` **to get the all picture files (jpg or Png) from the filesystem**.

Dataset for Get Metadata:
[image]

Get Metadata setting:
[image]

- Then I passed the output of Get Metadata to ForEach with `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

[image]

- After that in copy activity I took one `Set Variable activity` where **I created a Demo variable with string datatype** and in value I am concating the path with file name like `@concat('E:\images\',item().name)`.

[image]

- Now I am passing the above variable to script activity to insert that file into table with insert query as below

```sql
INSERT INTO ImageTable (Name, Photo)
SELECT '@{item().name}', BulkColumn
FROM Openrowset( Bulk '@{variables('demo')}', Single_Blob) as image
```

[image]

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Hi @PratikLad thanks for your reply.
I've followed your very clear example, and all is working except the Bulk Insert. The Script activity returns the error message: 
Cannot bulk load because the file "\\<FileServer IP>\<C Drive Share>\<Image Folder>\Test.jpg" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).
I've tried giving the file folder permissions, including the Everyone user with full permissions, but with no success. We don't have Active Directory, so I can't use the SQL Server logon user.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The INSERT I'm using is:
`INSERT INTO coDocumentBinary
 (coFileName, coBinaryData)
SELECT '@{item().PIC_PATHNAME}', BulkColumn
  FROM Openrowset( Bulk '@{variables('FilePath')}', Single_Blob) as image`

Comment: make sure you use same path till folder in both file share and Insert query. or Downgrade to integration runtime 5.21 and try by giving  `C:\<Image Folder>\Test.jpg` as path

Comment: Thanks @PratikLad, I couldn't get the network path working, so I copied the image files onto the SQL Server host machine and the local path worked fine in the bulk INSERT.